# How set rule in .htaccess when argument=argument?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?)argument=argument
```

but:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?)argumentext=argumentext
```

I find rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?)[a-zA-Z0-9_]=[a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

But this rule find only "=" and random text before and after, but i need when argument=value

Example:

```
IP - - [DATE] "GET /?value=value HTTP/1.1" 
IP - - [DATE] "GET /?random=random HTTP/1.1" 
IP - - [DATE] "GET /?qwerty=qwerty HTTP/1.1" 
IP - - [DATE] "GET /?randomvalues=randomvalues HTTP/1.1"
```

Need a rule when they **are equal**

Comment: it rules match to sometext=randomwords

Comment: "but i need when argument=value" - Then why not use `argument=value`? But what is `(?)` supposed to be doing in your regex? The literal `?` (query string delimiter) is not part of the query string itself.

Comment: because they are random, but they are equal.

Comment: "but i need when argument=value" - So, from your examples, you mean when `<argument>=<argument>`?

Comment: yes. sorry i edit post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule with a capture group and a back-reference:

```sh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=\1$
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```

Here `RewriteRule ^ - [G]` is used for testing only.

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Match start
- `([^=]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not `=` in capture group #1
- `=`: Match a `=`
- `\1`: Match same value as in capture group #1
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  "GET /?value=value HTTP/1.1" 
>  "GET /?random=random HTTP/1.1" 
>  "GET /?qwerty=qwerty HTTP/1.1" 
>  "GET /?randomvalues=randomvalues HTTP/1.1"
> ```

You can do something like the following to match `<something>=<something>` where the parameter name and value are the same:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(\w+)=\1(?:$|&)
```

Where `\1` is an internal backreference that matches the URL parameter name.

This `name=name` pair can occur anywhere in the query string, amongst other URL parameters. But only whole parameter names will match.